# Is there a way to provide serial tasks on terminal while a task is executing (without using a file)?

Tags: command-line, bash, job-control

Suppose there are 2 tasks `t1`, `t2` which can be executed in a serial way as below:

```bsh
t1 ; t2
# OR
t1 && t2
```

Now suppose I forgot to run `t2` and `t1` is already running; can I add `t2` to the pipeline so that it gets executed after `t1` finishes?

Answer (score 20):

Yes you can:

1. Pause the currently running job with the *suspend character* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.
2. Type `fg` or `%`, add what you want to the list and execute it, e.g.:

   ```
   fg ; systemctl suspend # or
   % ; systemctl suspend
   ```

   Since `fg` returns the return value of the job it resumed, list operators like `&&` and `||` work as expected:

   ```
   fg && echo "Finished successfully!" # or
   % && echo "Finished successfully!"
   ```

[`man bash`/JOB CONTROL](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc25) says about the suspend  character:

> Typing  the  *suspend*  character
>          (typically  `^Z`,  <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>)  while  a  process  is  running causes that
>          process to be stopped and returns control to `bash`. (…) The user may then manipulate the state of this
>          job, using the `bg` command to continue it  in  the  background,  the  `fg`
>          command  to  continue it in the foreground, or the `kill` command to kill
>          it.  A `^Z` takes effect immediately, and has the additional side  effect
>          of causing pending output and typeahead to be discarded.

`fg` is explained in [`man bash`/SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc30):

> fg [*jobspec*]
>                 Resume *jobspec* in the foreground, and make it the  current  job.
>                 If *jobspec* is not present, the shell's notion of the current job
>                 is used.  The return value is that of the  command  placed  into
>                 the  foreground,  or failure if run when job control is disabled
>                 or, when run with job  control  enabled,  if  *jobspec*  does  not
>                 specify  a valid job or *jobspec* specifies a job that was started
>                 without job control.

Further reading (aside from `man bash`) on job control:

- [TLDP Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide Chapter 15.1. Job Control Commands](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html)
- [DigitalOcean tutorial on How To Use Bash's Job Control](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-s-job-control-to-manage-foreground-and-background-processes)
- [Article “Prozesssteuerung” in the Ubuntuusers Wiki (German)](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Shell/Prozesssteuerung/)

Comment: +1 but it's a shame this doesn't work when you forget `t3` in `t1; t2; t3` or `t1 && t2 && t3`.

Comment: @JoL True that – `^Z^Z` and `%-;%+;t3` is good enough in some cases, but it's far from being a real solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this method here: https://superuser.com/questions/334272/how-to-run-a-command-after-an-already-running-existing-one-finishes

where you first do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to stop (suspend) the running one then you run the missed command like so: `fg && ./missed_cmd.sh` and it will run as soon as the `fg` finishes.

The `fg` (foreground command) will bring the suspended job online and the `&&` will ensure that the missed command is only run if the first command succeeds.